# PHP error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot access offset of type string on string

Tags: php, api

I understand there are many similar "TypeError: Cannot access offset of type string on string" but everyone is different, and i read them. How do I skip over the nested values? We only need address_line_1, City etc.

this is the code:

```
foreach ($jd as $line) {
  if(!in_array($line['phone'], array_column($csv, 'phone'))){
    $newarray[sizeof($newarray)]=$line; //add unique row
    fputcsv($file, $line); //update the master csv file
  }
}
```

This is what some of the data looks like

```
                [address_line_1] => 10860 Larry Dr, Northglenn, CO 80233
                [address_line_2] => 
                [anonymous] => 
                [blocked] => 
                [campaign_id] => o1RqNONn9jHnnBRd1M9A
                [campaign_name] => K1Keto  Camp 4/28
                [city] => Northglenn
                [company] => 
                [country] => US
                [created_date_unix] => 1656104474
                [customer_card] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [customer_group] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => P67902g06ZfaN1O64p08
                                [name] => Prospect
                            )

                    )

                [email] => lovemyhd@gmail.com
                [enabled] => 1
                [first_name] => William
                [full_address] => 10860 Larry Dr, Northglenn, CO 80233, USA
                [geocode_success] => 1
                [google_place_id] => ChIJy8IV-5p2bIcRE9IovuASaOY
                [id] => y2JWmaLGP1TdP0qoMzM5
                [internal_id] => 
                [last_name] => Wolters
                [lat] => 39.8933644
                [lifetime_value] => Array
```

Comment: Where is `phone` in the data?

Comment: I do not see `phone` anywhere in that data example, [provide a complete, minimalistic and reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: And re the error,  presumably `$line` is actually a string and not an array. You didn't show what the `$jd` variable is that it comes from.

Comment: @Barmar this is a piece of the data we decided test uniqueness with that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if `$line` is an array before trying to index it.

```
if(is_array($line) && !in_array($line['phone'], array_column($csv, 'phone'))){
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try 2 things:

is_array($line) to see if $line is really an Array

```
if(is_array($line)){...}
```

and see if the nodes really exist using the isset();

```
if (isset($line['email']) ) {....}
```